# Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call:

Tags: visualforce

> Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call:
>
> [] Error is in expression '{!SavingContact}' in component  in page onaccountcontatdisplayvf: Class.OnAccountContatDisplay.SavingContact: line 85, column 1

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class OnAccountContatDisplay 
{
    Private ID Acctid                    {get;set;}
    public Account acc                   {get;set;}
    public list<COntact> con3            {get;set;}  
    public  COntact con1                 {get;set;}  
    public  COntact con2                 {get;set;}  
    public  COntact conA                 {get;set;} 
    public  COntact conB                 {get;set;} 
    Public contact  contact              {get;set;} 
    public boolean temp1  {get;set;}
   //public boolean temp1  {get;set;}  
    public boolean temp2  {get;set;}
    public string Amount {get;set;} 
    public String AccountType {get;set;}

    Public OnAccountContatDisplay (Apexpages.standardController controller)

    {
        temp1=true;
        temp2=false;
        con2 = new contact();
        con1 = new contact();
        con2.Accountid = Acctid;
        con1.Accountid = Acctid;

        Acctid = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
        system.debug('acc===>'+Acctid);
        con3 = new list<contact>();

         con3 = [select  Accountid,LastName,FirstName,Email,Phone,Department,Language_Preference__c,Birth_Date__c,Primary_Contact__c
         from contact where Accountid =:Acctid order by primary_contact__c limit 2];

         con2 = new contact();
         con1 = new contact();            

        for(contact c:con3)
     {
         if(c.primary_contact__c == true)

            {        
               con1 = new contact();        
               con1=c;
            }
         else
           {          
               con2 = new contact();                        
               con2=c;
           }
     }

    }

    public List<SelectOption> getItems()
    {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
        options.add(new SelectOption('Single','Single'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Joint','Joint'));
        return options;
    }


    Public PageReference actionSave()
    {
        system.debug('Amount::'+AccountType);

        if(AccountType =='Joint')
        {
           temp1=true;
           system.debug('temp1==>'+temp1);

           temp2=true;      
          system.debug('temp2==>'+temp2);
        }    

        return null;
    }

    Public PageReference SavingContact()

    {
            contact c1 = con1;
            contact c  = con2;
            update c1;  
            update c;            
            pagereference page=new pagereference('/'+acctid);
            Page.setRedirect(true);
            return Page;
    }

}
```

**Visualforce**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="OnAccountContatDisplay">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:selectRadio value="{!AccountType}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!actionSave}"/>
      </apex:selectRadio>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Accounts">
         <apex:pageblockbuttons >
      <apex:commandButton value="save" action="{!SavingContact}"/ >
      </apex:pageblockbuttons>

           <apex:pageBlockSection title="Primary Contacts" columns="2" rendered="{!temp1}">

                <apex:inputfield value="{!con1.FirstName}"/>
                 <apex:inputfield value="{!con1.LastName}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con1.Email}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con1.Phone}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con1.Department}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con1.Language_Preference__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con1.Birth_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con1.Primary_Contact__c}"/>
                </apex:pageblocksection>


                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Secondary Contacts" columns="2" rendered="{!temp2}">


                <apex:inputfield value="{!con2.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con2.LastName}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con2.Email}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con2.Phone}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con2.Department}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con2.Language_Preference__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con2.Birth_Date__c}"/>
                <apex:inputfield value="{!con2.Primary_Contact__c}"/>
                </apex:pageblocksection>





        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error is pretty clear about the problem: you're trying to perform a DML `update` on a record that doesn't contain an `Id` value, that is, a record that doesn't yet exist in the database.

This stems from incorrect logic in your constructor.

```
    con3 = new list<contact>();
     con3 = [select  Accountid,LastName,FirstName,Email,Phone,Department,Language_Preference__c,Birth_Date__c,Primary_Contact__c
     from contact where Accountid =:Acctid order by primary_contact__c limit 2];
     con2 = new contact();
     con1 = new contact();  

    for(contact c:con3) {
     if(c.primary_contact__c == true) {        
           con1 = new contact();        
           con1=c;
        } else {          
           con2 = new contact();                        
           con2=c;
       }
```

If your query returns no records, `con1` and `con2` are just empty Contact records that have never been inserted.

I'm not going to tell you exactly how to fix this, because what you really need to do is step back and think through your logic for the different situations that are possible here:

- Account with >= 2 Contacts, one of them primary
- Account with >= 2 Contacts, no primary
- Account with >= 2 Contacts, multiple primary
- Account with 1 Contact, one primary
- Account with 1 Contact, no primary
- Account with no Contacts

(Of course, other code in your org *could* prohibit one or more of these options, but we don't know that right now).

You should then carefully reimplement your logic to take these possibilities into account, which could involve inserting Contacts, displaying an error, using an `upsert`, or something else entirely.

You should also remove the instances of this construction:

```
           con1 = new contact();        
           con1=c;
```

You do not need to initialize your variables twice.

Comment: Hi,
I am retriving one contact which has primary contact is true.

Comment: But when account has only one contact then my requirement is i have insert second contact for the same account.
But this not possible .

Error : ID is not specified  for update opration.

Comment: How to resolve this problme

Comment: You need to decide how to resolve that, as I discuss above. You can choose to perform an `upsert` instead of an `update`, if the Contact data is populated in your Visualforce page, but you'll need to make sure that your new Contacts have their `AccountId` set, along with other required fields like `LastName`.

Answer (score 2):

**UDPATED** based on Derek's comments.

On top of other issues, your primary issue as the error suggests:

> Update failed. First exception on row 0; first error: MISSING_ARGUMENT, Id not specified in an update call

Is because you don't have `Id` for the records which were retrieved from the query and later assigned to the variables `c1` and `c` in `SavingContact` method, which you are trying to update.

While you can include the `Id` field in the as below:

```
con3 = [select Id, <all other fields> FROM  contact where <condition>];
```

Your primary problem still remains where you are assigning the `con1` and `con2` variables with the records as retrieved in the SOQL within the iteration. You are most likely ending up with new instance of the `Contact` object which does not include an `Id` (as the record does not exist yet).

In your current code, it is very likely that only one of the values is getting assigned to the record as retrieved in the SOQL unless you really get two records where `pimary_contact__c` values are `true` and `false` respectively.

You should review your code to make sure how do you want to handle the `update` operation.

```
for(contact c : con3) {
    if(c.primary_contact__c == true) {
        ... // con1 remains unassigned with record from SOQL if always true, is then only a new instance with no Id available
    } else {
        ... // con2 remains unassigned with record from SOQL if always false, is then only a new instance with no Id available
    }
 }
```

Comment: Even if you don't explicitly query for it, the Id of an SObject is _always_ included in a query result. You can run the following in an execute anonymous window to verify: `Account acct = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
system.debug(acct.Id);` If the object has multiple record types, then recordTypeId is also implicitly queried. Including the Id/RecordTypeId fields in your query is still good practice though.

Comment: Good point. Well, in this case it just seems to be an unassigned variable which the OP is trying to update later in the code and that it was never assigned with the record as retrieved in the SOQL. There's definitely more than just the `Id` issue here.

Comment: Thanks Jayant for such nice exaplanation.
My code run due to i not Initialize Heap size.

Comment: You don’t initialize heap size in Salesforce. It’s governed by Salesforce. Just make sure you refactor your code accordingly to get past the errors